# How can I clear autocomplete values

Tags: reactjs, autocomplete, material-ui

I am working with material ui autocomplete.

```
 <Autocomplete
    multiple
    id="tags-outlined"
    options={options}
    getOptionLabel={(option) => option && option.name}
    value={catArray}
    onChange={handleCategoryFilter}
    filterSelectedOptions
    renderInput={(params) => (
     <TextField
      {...params}
      variant="outlined"
      placeholder="Categories"
     />
    )}
/>
```

Firstly I want selected value not to show in options secondly I want to clear autocomplete. Can you please guide me how can I do these things.

I am clearing the values by `setCatArray([])` but it is not workinh

Comment: Can you provide a codesandbox?

Comment: What do you mean by clearing autocomplete?

Comment: `setCatArray([])`

Comment: You want a way to clear autocomplete programmatically?

Comment: yes ... I want to clear it programmatically

Comment: You can set options to an empty array. It worked on my machine

Comment: No i want to clear selected values, not options

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220837/discussion-between-nearhuscarl-and-kinza).

Answer (score 1):

You can use material ui autocomplete's default prop `filterSelectedOptions`. If true, it will hide the selected options from the list box.

For clearing the values of autocomplete, it gives default clear icon at the end of the select box. you can clear it from there.

Try my sandbox [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-s55hf?file=/demo.js). Also try some more material ui demos [here](https://material-ui.com/components/autocomplete/).

`UPDATE`: If you want to manage clearing values you can use `value` prop of autocomplete and manage it in `onchange` by updating it's value.

```
 <Autocomplete
    multiple
    id="tags-outlined"
    options={top100Films}
    value={values}
    getOptionSelected={(option, value) => value.title === option.title}
    getOptionLabel={(option) => option.title}
    filterSelectedOptions
    onChange={(e, valueTags) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      const valuesArray = [];
      valueTags.forEach((valueTag) => {
        valuesArray.push({
          title: top100Films
            .filter((tag) => valueTag.title === tag.title)
            .shift().title
        });
      });
      setValues(valuesArray);
    }}
    renderInput={(params) => (
      <TextField
        {...params}
        variant="outlined"
        label="filterSelectedOptions"
        placeholder="Favorites"
      />
    )}
  />
```

Comment: I have used filterSelectedOptions. you can see in question

Comment: yes ... thats the issue it is not clearing the value even after setting the array to empty

Comment: You need to set that value array which you are clearing or changing as an option to autocomplete. `options={values}` instead of `options={options}`

Comment: no i don't want to clear the options. I want to clear the selected values

Comment: @kinza i've updated my sandbox link. please check is that what you wanted ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding `autocomplete=false` to the list of properties in the component?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to filter out selected options from autocomplete. Pass `filterSelectedOptions={true}` to your component

Secondly, you can clear the value by taking control of the selected values and setting it to an empty array. Here is my complete example

```
const options = ["one", "two", "three", "four"];

export default function MyAutocomplete() {
  const [values, setValues] = React.useState<string[]>([]);
  const onChange = (_, value) => {
    setValues(value);
  };
  const clearSelected = () => {
    setValues([]);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={clearSelected}>Clear selected</button>
      <Autocomplete
        multiple
        id="tags-outlined"
        options={options}
        getOptionLabel={(option) => option}
        value={values}
        onChange={onChange}
        filterSelectedOptions
        renderInput={(params) => (
          <TextField {...params} variant="outlined" placeholder="Categories" />
        )}
      />
    </>
  );
}
```

### Live Example

[image: Edit Material-UI Autocomplete Clear Selected]

Comment: yes i'm clearing by setting value to empty array but it is not working

Answer (score 0):

```
    const options = ["one", "two", "three", "four"];

export default function MyAutocomplete() {
  const [values, setValues] = React.useState([]);
  const onChange = (_, value) => {
    setValues(value);
  };
  const clearSelected = () => {
    setValues([]);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={clearSelected}>Clear selected</button>
      <Autocomplete
        multiple
        id="tags-outlined"
        options={options}
        getOptionLabel={(option) => option}
        value={values}
        onChange={onChange}
        filterSelectedOptions
        renderInput={(params) => (
          <TextField {...params} variant="outlined" placeholder="Categories" />
        )}
      />
    </>
  );
}
```